# Magento Iterator Vs Foreach Loop How to return an array?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, collection, performance

I've encountered a problem where my foreach loop is causing a 504 Gateway timeout error so I did some research and found that for large collections it is better to use the `core/resource_iterator` and the `walk()` function.

This has definitely improved performance but I have lost the ability to return the array the I need from when I call my custom function.

`$this->getAllDataFromTable()`

Here is what I mean: **This function will get all the data from the table and return the `$array` variable which I can do stuff with - but is very expensive and times out with a 504 error.**

```
public static function getAllDataFromTable()
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom/table');
    $collection = $model->getCollection();
    $array = array();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $array[] = $item->getData();
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Using the iterator: The iterator is more efficient but I can only do stuff with the last row, I would like a similar `$array` returned so I can do stuff with it.

```
/**
 * Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Iterator
 */
public function getAllDataFromTable()
{
    $ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('custom/table')->getCollection();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($ordersCollection->getSelect(),
        array(array($this, 'orderCallback'))
    );
}

public function orderCallback($args)
{
  return $args['row'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can simply assign a variable to the class and do something like this:

```
private $data = [];

public function getAllDataFromTable()
{
    $ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('custom/table')->getCollection();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($ordersCollection->getSelect(),
        array(array($this, 'orderCallback'))
    );
    return $this->data;
}

public function orderCallback($args)
{
    $this->data[] = $args['row'];
}
```

Also, depending what you want to do with it (when you say "return the `$array` variable which I can do stuff with") you can add that logic directly in the callback method and that'll save you one array to fill and return.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've gone back to getting a 504 again! How can I make this more efficient as there's only 215 rows in the table?

Comment: @user1704524 sounds weird that you get a 504. What's your time limit configuration on your server ?

Comment: I have it set to `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); ` It gets even weirderer, I only get the timeout in the office so I assumed that there is a memory leak somewhere in the loop hence wanting to fix it using the iterator to fix the leak.

Comment: @user1704524 did you manage to find the root cause in the end ?

Comment: Well, not for the 504 but the array worked so I accepted the answer, but still trying to find out why the timeout is happening.

Comment: @user1704524 feel free to open a new question. Also try to use the Varien PRofiler to find out where the leak comes from